# Add system user to CentOS 6

Tags: centos6, user-management

I need help adding a system user to my CentOS server. I have two commands that works on Ubuntu Server, however I have to find a replacement for CentOS while keeping the same result. The commands are:

```
sudo adduser --system --shell /bin/sh --gecos 'Git Version Control' --group --disabled-password --home /home/git git
sudo adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' gitlab
```

The options that I can't find on CentOS are --system, --disabled-password and --disabled-login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to take a look at `man useradd`.  You seem to have a good grasp of what you want to do but `adduser` = `useradd` in RHEL/CentOS.

- `-r` = `--system`
- For the other options, I think you just want to lock the account with `passwd -l <username>` after the account is created.

Make sure empty passwords are not allowed by PAM;

Look in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` and remove `nullok` from the `pam_unix.so` lines (if applicable.)

[Ubuntu's `adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/adduser.8.html)
& [`useradd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd)

Comment: -r doesn't create the homedir. What if I need a system user which can login not via password but via ssh and with his own user home directory?

Comment: Right, `-m` creates the home directory, `-r` just makes the UID < 500 which is convention for a system account. Look at all the options available for `useradd`, there aren't too many.

Comment: can I use -r and -m together?

Comment: Sure, can! They are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: one last question: in the commands of Ubuntu I have the --group option which (from the docs) when combined with --system, creates a group with the same name and ID as the system user. If not combined with --system, a group with the given name is created. As on Ubuntu the --system option is specified, what should I do on CentOS to get the same result?

Comment: That's default behavior -- I just tested to confirm.